# White iphone Home button defect?

Tags: iphone, hardware-recommendation, hardware

Recently 1 week back I bought a new white iphone... I have found 1 problem in iphone... Actually the problem is: white iphone home button is little bit deep.. i can feel edges/corner while pressing home button. I think it shouldn't be like that.

Anyone have faced similar problem ? ... Is this problem with every white iphone devices ? ... or only my device is defective ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that when you press the home button you can feel the edges of the surrounding glass?  If so I think that is probably normal.  It should be flush with the glass when NOT pressed though.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can feel the edges of the button on both my black iPhone 4 even when the button isn't depressed - so your description alone doesn't necessarily mean there is a defect (but you should be very happy with your new purchase and it could very well be a defect).

If you can go to any retail (cell carrier or Apple) store and compare your device to others (or have friends with any iPhone 4 to compare) it will be very easy for anyone to agree if your phone's button is different than the rest. No matter where you bought the phone - Apple will exchange it if the hardware is defective at no cost.

You also can return a new phone to the seller within 30 days - but getting it in the hands of an Apple tech will be the fastest way to know it's covered or a defect - or if it's just a normal variation of the manufacturing process.

Comment: Thanks for reply... i went to iStore... and saw some white iphone4 devices... yeah issue is same... there is some edges round the corners in iphone4... but in ipods there are no as such... and 1 more reason.. that i have screen guard over my screen thats why i feel slightly more... Apple Store guys told me your iphone is pretty normal and fine.. i think i not need to worry about that ;)

Comment: Hooray and thanks for replying. The question and answer are much better when the story has a conclusion!